# How to upgrade my sata hdd 1tb to sata ssd 512gb with the same windows os that is installed?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, laptop, ssd

Constraints:

1. My laptop has only 1 slot for storage space.

Requirements:

1. I need the same windows os 10 to be present on the ssd with all the settings and apps without loosing the genuine windows key.
2. I only need to clone my windows installed drive i.e. c drive from sata hdd to sata ssd, I don't need other drives.

Comment: Most SSD manufacturers supply cloning software to do precisely this. What you need is an external enclosure so you can mount both at once.

Comment: There are no other drives if you only have one HDD. You mean *partitions* and no, the thing you call "drive C:\" is not the only partition you need, you also need the ESP (EFI System Partition) at the very least. And the license isn't store in the drive anyway. Better to have backups and install fresh anyway, the questions you posted here show you don't know enough to do that safely; cloning to a smaller drive is NOT trivial.

Comment: Shrink your system partition to something smaller than 512GB then clone the disk to the smaller drive, skipping, the unallocated partition. You do need the other partitions otherwise Windows won’t boot.

Comment: Your problem is your laptop only allows one drive to be installed at a time. You will need to buy an external SATA USB device to plug in the SSD drive. Then you will have to boot to something like Clonezilla to transfer the 1TB to the 512GB SSD. But as @Ramhound stated, you have to first shrink the drive as a 1TB partition layout will not fit on a 512GB drive.

Comment: You have two basic steps here, and both have been asked and answered previously on this site. I have marked on such duplicate: cloning a drive to a smaller drive. The other is cloning with only one slot, which means you'll be cloning from your internal disk to an external disk (or the other way around, that's fine too). Here's a search that has a lot of results regarding this: https://superuser.com/search?q=clone+external